# Pythonic way to get closest point for each point in a data frame (Nearest Neighbour)

Tags: python, loops, pandas, nearest-neighbor

I have a list of locations and towers. I'm trying to find out, for each location, what the closest tower is. I've come up with a way that works, but I'm pretty sure it's a very inefficient way of doing it.

How would I do this in a more pythonic manner?

I have about 4,000 locations and 11,000 towers. I'm currently:

1. looping through each location
2. finding the distance to all the towers
3. sorting by distance
4. taking the closest one then appending that to the 'nearest_tower' data frame.

Here's the code:

```
nearest_tower = pd.DataFrame()

for i, location_rows in d[["Name", "Lat", "Long"]].T.iteritems():
    tower_coords["Distance_km"] =  tower_coords.apply(lambda row: distance_on_unit_sphere(location_rows ["Lat"], location_rows ["Long"], row['DIGITAL_LATITUDE'], row['DIGITAL_LONGITUDE'])*6373, axis=1)
    a = tower_coords.sort(['Distance_km'], ascending = 1)[:1][["SITE_NUMBER", "DIGITAL_LATITUDE", "DIGITAL_LONGITUDE", "Distance_km"]]
    a["Location_Name"] = location_rows ["Name"]
    a["Location_Lat"] = location_rows ["Lat"]
    a["Location_Long"] = location_rows ["Long"]
    nearest_tower = nearest_tower.append(a)
    print(i)
```

Tower_coords looks like this:

```
SITE_NUMBER    DIGITAL_LATITUDE      DIGITAL_LONGITUDE
1                67.21                     -30.432
...
```

Comment: what is tower_coords? what does that look like?

Comment: It would probably be if the distances to the local towers were put in a heap, so you could simply pop off the closest tower. But probably there are even more efficient data structures to solve this problem, like the k-d tree @Hbcdev mentions

Comment: @usethedeathstar example of file added, it just shows the longitude and latitude of a tower

Comment: no digital altitude to take into account for the distances? how do you calculate distances? not with ECEF coords i guess? how does distance_on_unit_sphere work and where does it come from?

Comment: I used the function on this page http://www.johndcook.com/python_longitude_latitude.html - rough calculation I gather, assumes spherical cow.

Comment: So for all 4.000 locations you apply the distance function to all 11.000 towers? That seems rather wasteful, as most towers are *not* near. You could already greatly reduce the work by binning all the towers on certain lat/long combinations, such that you only have to iterate over a small subset of all the towers to find your best match.

Answer (score 1):

First up, use `min` 
([Python doc here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min)) to find the nearest. You can supply a `key` argument after the iterable (which will be your lambda function).

It'd be more pythonic to use a class instead of a Hash-like structure instead of your `a` object. Implementations like PyPy will be more efficient dealing with class property accesses than with hash-like accesses.

This whole function can be made into a `map` operation. You're taking one structure and mapping it to another structure with a 1-1 correspondence between elements, which makes this a `map`.

Lastly (and this isn't about being Pythonic but it is important), you should use a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree) structure for efficiently finding nearest points.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Someone explains [how to do a k-d tree search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28186940/4212158) in Pandas here!

[Here is a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28613358/4212158) in another question which leverages the complex data type (a builtin in Python and Numpy) which is faster than looping but uses a lot of memory.

There is an issue open in the Pandas Github [proposing a get_nearest method](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8845) which would do a k-d tree search like @Hbcdev mentioned. <s>I myself am trying to figure out how to implement a kNN search in Pandas.</s>