# Merge/Join 2 DataFrames by complex criteria

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, scikit-learn, dataframe

I have 2 large datasets (large in terms of 70K to 110K each). I want to correlate/compare both and find which items from set2 can be found in set1 based on some conditions/criteria.

My current strategy is to sort both lists by common fields and then run nested `for` loops, perform conditional `if` tests, aggregate predefined dict with items which were found and those that did not match.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [{'a': 56, 'b': '38', 'c': '11', 'd': '10', 'e': 65},
         {'a': 31, 'b': '12', 'c': '26', 'd': '99', 'e': 71},
         {'a': 70, 'b': '49', 'c': '40', 'd': '227', 'e': 1},
         {'a': 3, 'b': '85', 'c': '32', 'd': '46', 'e': 70},]
list2 = [{'a': 56, 'b': '38', 'c': '11', 'd': '10', 'e': 65},
         {'a': 145, 'b': '108', 'c': '123', 'd': '84', 'e': 3},
         {'a': 113, 'b': '144', 'c': '183', 'd': '7', 'e': 12},
         {'a': 144, 'b': '60', 'c': '46', 'd': '106', 'e': 148},
         {'a': 57, 'b': '87', 'c': '51', 'd': '95', 'e': 187},
         {'a': 41, 'b': '12', 'c': '26', 'd': '99', 'e': 71},
         {'a': 80, 'b': '49', 'c': '40', 'd': '227', 'e': 1},
         {'a': 3, 'b': '85', 'c': '32', 'd': '46', 'e': 70},
         {'a': 107, 'b': '95', 'c': '81', 'd': '15', 'e': 25},
         {'a': 138, 'b': '97', 'c': '38', 'd': '28', 'e': 171}]

re_dict = dict([('found', []), ('alien', [])])

for L2 in list2:
    for L1 in list1:
        if (L1['a']-5 <= L2['a'] <= L2['a']+10) and L2['c'][-1:] in L1['c'][-1:]:
            if (65 <= L2['e'] <= 75):
                L2.update({'e': 'some value'})
            re_dict['found'].append(L2)
            list1.remove(L1)
            break # break out from the inner loop
    else: # if the inner loop traversed entire list, there were no matches
        re_dict['alien'].append(L2)
```

Above yields desired results:

```
re_dict
{'alien': [{'a': 145, 'b': '108', 'c': '123', 'd': '84', 'e': 3},
  {'a': 113, 'b': '144', 'c': '183', 'd': '7', 'e': 12},
  {'a': 57, 'b': '87', 'c': '51', 'd': '95', 'e': 187},
  {'a': 41, 'b': '12', 'c': '26', 'd': '99', 'e': 71},
  {'a': 107, 'b': '95', 'c': '81', 'd': '15', 'e': 25},
  {'a': 138, 'b': '97', 'c': '38', 'd': '28', 'e': 171}],
 'found': [{'a': 56, 'b': '38', 'c': '11', 'd': '10', 'e': 'some value'},
  {'a': 144, 'b': '60', 'c': '46', 'd': '106', 'e': 148},
  {'a': 80, 'b': '49', 'c': '40', 'd': '227', 'e': 1},
  {'a': 3, 'b': '85', 'c': '32', 'd': '46', 'e': 'some value'}]}
```

So it does the job, but is obviously not very efficient and seems like ideal job for `pandas`.

I think it would be ideal if I could merge/join two `DataFrames`, but I can't figure it out how to merge on the complex criterion. Also my datasets are not equal in size.

Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2)

pd.merge(df1,df2,on='d',how='outer')
   a_x  b_x  c_x    d  e_x  a_y  b_y  c_y  e_y
0   56   38   11   10   65   56   38   11   65
1   31   12   26   99   71   41   12   26   71
2   70   49   40  227    1   80   49   40    1
3    3   85   32   46   70    3   85   32   70
4  NaN  NaN  NaN   84  NaN  145  108  123    3
5  NaN  NaN  NaN    7  NaN  113  144  183   12
6  NaN  NaN  NaN  106  NaN  144   60   46  148
7  NaN  NaN  NaN   95  NaN   57   87   51  187
8  NaN  NaN  NaN   15  NaN  107   95   81   25
9  NaN  NaN  NaN   28  NaN  138   97   38  171
```

It merges only when say *d* column is exactly equal in both `df1` and `df2`.
What I prefer is to be able to define lets say a range, that is if  `df2['d']-5 <= df1['d'] <= df2['d']+5` it's still ok and it means, that these lines in both dataframes are candidates to be merged, only if test fails `df1` columns are filled with *NaN* (like in above example).

This way in several steps I could mimic my nested for-for loops, and hopefully that would be quicker?

Any suggestion/hint/example would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

pandas currently lacks direct support for "nearby" queries, though I have a [pull request](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/9258) up to add some basic functionality (not enough for your use-case).

Fortunately, the scientific Python ecosystem gives you the tools you need to do this yourself.

The efficient way to join on nearby locations is to use a tree data structure, as described nicely in the [scikit-learn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#nearest-neighbor-algorithms). Both SciPy and scikit-learn have suitable KDTree implementations.

It's not easy (or efficient) to use entirely ad-hoc rules, but you can do nearest neighbor lookups efficiently as long as you have a well defined distance metric. I believe scikit-learn's KDTree even lets you define your own distance metric, but we'll stick to normal Euclidean distance to continue your example:

```py
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as KDTree
import pandas as pd

# for each row in df2, we want to join the nearest row in df1
# based on the column "d"
join_cols = ['d']
tree = KDTree(df1[join_cols])
distance, indices = tree.query(df2[join_cols])
df1_near_2 = df1.take(indices).reset_index(drop=True)

left = df1_near_2.rename(columns=lambda l: 'x_' + l)
right = df2.rename(columns=lambda l: 'y_' + l)
merged = pd.concat([left, right], axis=1)
```

This results in:

```
   x_a x_b x_c  x_d  x_e  y_a  y_b  y_c  y_d  y_e
0   56  38  11   10   65   56   38   11   10   65
1   31  12  26   99   71  145  108  123   84    3
2   56  38  11   10   65  113  144  183    7   12
3   31  12  26   99   71  144   60   46  106  148
4   31  12  26   99   71   57   87   51   95  187
5   31  12  26   99   71   41   12   26   99   71
6   70  49  40  227    1   80   49   40  227    1
7    3  85  32   46   70    3   85   32   46   70
8   56  38  11   10   65  107   95   81   15   25
9   56  38  11   10   65  138   97   38   28  171
```

If you want to merge based on nearness for multiple columns, it's as simple as setting `join_cols = ['d', 'e', 'f']`.