# How to speed up nearest search in Pandas (perhaps by vectorizing code)

Tags: python, pandas, distance, vectorization, nearest-neighbor

I have two dataframes.  Each one contains locations (X,Y) and a value for that point.  For each point in the first dataframe I want to find the closest point in the second dataframe and then find the difference.  I have code that is working, but it uses a for loop, which is slow.

Any suggestions for how to speed this up?  I know that it is generally a good idea to get rid of for loops in pandas, for performance, but I don't see how to do that in this case.

Here is some sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3), columns=['val', 'X', 'Y'])
df2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3), columns=['val', 'X', 'Y'])

nearest=df1.copy()  #CORRECTION.  This had been just =df1 which caused a problem when trying to compare to answers submitted.

for idx,row in nearest.iterrows():
#Find the X,Y points closest to the selected point:
    closest=df2.ix[((df2['X']-row['X'])**2+(df2['Y']-row['Y'])**2).idxmin()]
    #Set the max to the difference between the current row and the nearest one.
    nearest.loc[idx,'val']= df1.loc[idx,'val'] - closest['val']
```

As I am using this on larger dataframes, it takes a long time to do the calculation.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cool solution to your problem involves leveraging the `complex` data type (builtin in python and numpy).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3), columns=['val', 'X', 'Y'])
df2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3), columns=['val', 'X', 'Y'])

# dataframes to numpy arrays of complex numbers
p1 = (df1['X'] + 1j * df1['Y']).values
p2 = (df2['X'] + 1j * df2['Y']).values

# calculate all the distances, between each point in
# df1 and each point in df2 (using an array-broadcasting trick)
all_dists = abs(p1[..., np.newaxis] - p2)

# find indices of the minimal distance from df1 to df2,
# and from df2 to df1
nearest_idxs1 = np.argmin(all_dists, axis = 0)
nearest_idxs2 = np.argmin(all_dists, axis = 1)

# extract the rows from the dataframes
nearest_points1 = df1.ix[nearest_idxs1].reset_index()
nearest_points2 = df2.ix[nearest_idxs2].reset_index()
```

This is probably much faster than using a loop, but if your series turn out to be huge, it will consume a lot of memory (quadratic in number of points).

Also, this solution works if the sets of points are of different lenths.

---

Here's a concrete example demostrating how this works:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([ [987, 0, 0], [888, 2,2], [2345, 3,3] ], columns=['val', 'X', 'Y'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([ [ 1000, 1, 1 ], [2000, 9, 9] ] , columns=['val', 'X', 'Y'])

df1
    val  X  Y
0   987  0  0
1   888  2  2
2  2345  3  3

df2
    val  X  Y
0  1000  1  1
1  2000  9  9
```

Here, for every point in df1, df2[0]=(1,1) is the nearest point (as shown in `nearest_idxs2` below). Considering the opposite problem, for (1,1), either (0,0) or (2,2) are the nearest, and for (9,9), df1[1]=(3,3) is the nearest (as shown in `nearest_idxs1` below).

```
p1 = (df1['X'] + 1j * df1['Y']).values
p2 = (df2['X'] + 1j * df2['Y']).values
all_dists = abs(p1[..., np.newaxis] - p2)
nearest_idxs1 = np.argmin(all_dists, axis = 0)
nearest_idxs2 = np.argmin(all_dists, axis = 1)

nearest_idxs1
array([0, 2])
nearest_idxs2
array([0, 0, 0])

# It's nearest_points2 you're after:
nearest_points2 = df2.ix[nearest_idxs2].reset_index()

nearest_points2
   index   val  X  Y
0      0  1000  1  1
1      0  1000  1  1
2      0  1000  1  1

df1['val'] - nearest_points2['val']
0     -13
1    -112
2    1345
```

To solve the opposite problem (for each point in df2, find nearest in df1), take `nearest_points1` and `df2['val'] - nearest_points1['val']`

Comment: I like it.  Although, something is not working out correctly.  I did also try swapping the axis, as you suggested.  I believe that if I run the two versions of the code, then nearest and nearest_points1 should be identical.  But, they aren't.  nearest_points1 (and 2) ends up with some repeat values and some missing values.

Comment: That's because a point in df2 can be the nearest to more than one point in df1, or to no points at all in df1.

Comment: How can a point in df2 not a nearest point in df1?  For any point, at least one point must be nearest (there could be more, but with randoms like this example, that is unlikely)

Comment: Yes, I agree. In my comment above I switched to roles of df1 and df2. So: a point in df1 can be the nearest to more than one point in df2.

Comment: I tried making df1 7 rows and df2 5 rows.  Since df1 has 7 rows, i would expect that for each of those 7 points, it should find a nearest, but instead nearest_points1 ends up with only 5 rows.  And, every time I run it there are repeat rows in nearest_points1 (which seems very unlikely for random data)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71286/discussion-between-adam-and-shx2).

Comment: I hadn't been using a copy(), so my code changed df1, and then I was getting different results from your version.  So, I fixed it, and now your code does give the same results as mine.

Comment: Other interesting result is that for smaller sizes this is faster.  But, for larger sized dataframes, this is actually slower then the original code.  I think that it must be going to virtual memory to hold the large data, and that slows it down, although it does work.